# doxygen not resolving macro correctly

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, doxygen, call-graph

i am using doxygen 1.8.11 together with the eclipse plugin eclox. i tried to generate the call graph for my source files. when i checked in one of the files i noticed that the call graph contained a function call which is actually disabled by a `#define`  my expectation was not to see this function call in the call-graph.

on top of the source file :

```
#define MACRO_NAME   FALSE

....

void Func_1(int *p)
{
   ....
#if (MACRO_NAME == TRUE)
        Func_Call_2()
#else
        Func_Call_3()
#endif 
}
```

FALSE and TRUE are defined in one of the headers i included in the settings in "Include Paths" and i also get a hyperlink in the html report for FALSE and TRUE so doxygen is able to find the definition.

both Func_Call_2 and Func_Call_3() are drawn in the call graph, when actually i only want to see Func_Call_3().

my settings in the doxyfile are:

```
Enable Preprocessing      YES
Macro Expansion           NO
Expand Only Predefined    NO
Search Includes           YES
Extract All               YES
Extract Static            YES
```

i also tried with `Macro Expansion` YES but then i got no call-graph for this function `Func_1` at all only after setting it back to NO the call graph is drawn again in the html file

the header file in which `FALSE/TRUE` are defined starts like this:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

.....

#ifndef TRUE
   #define TRUE   1
#endif

#ifndef FALSE
   #define FALSE  0
#endif
```

is there any other setting i can try ? so that doxygen will draw the call-graph without the disabled code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following suggestions:

- Don't use `TRUE` and `FALSE` but `1` and `0` directly in the definition of `MACRO_NAME` and in the condition.
- Don't set a value for `MACRO_NAME` but check whether it is defined or not.
- Set Macro Expandion to YES and Expand Only Predefined to YES. Then set [Predefined](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_predefined) and/or [Expand As Defined](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_expand_as_defined) to include the relevant macro's.